# How to create a file in github repo with content using Python CLI

Tags: python, github-api

I am trying to create a github repo with a file, repo created successfully but when I try to create the file it returning, "Not Found" message.

```json
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}
```

**create_repo**

```py
def create_repo(repo_name, file_name, file_content):
    url = 'https://api.github.com/user/repos'
    headers = {"Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json"}
    data = {'name': repo_name}
    r = requests.post(url, auth=(USERNAME,TOKEN), headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    print("Repo created")

    # https://api.github.com/repos/InViN-test/test_repo1/contents/test.txt

    data = {
        "branch": "master",
        'message': 'Initial commit', 
        "path": file_name, 
        'content': b64encode(file_content.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'), 
        "committer": json.dumps({"name": USERNAME, "email": "myemail@gmail.com"}),
    }
    response = requests.put(f"{url}/{USERNAME}/{repo_name}/contents/{file_name}", auth=(USERNAME,TOKEN), headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    print(response.text)
```

I am not sure, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

My bad the URL was different. I keeping this question in-case if someone trying to do same as me.

```py
def create_repo(repo_name, file_name, file_content):
    headers = {"Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json", "Authorization": f"token {TOKEN}"}
    data = {'name': repo_name}
    r = requests.post("https://api.github.com/user/repos", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    print("Repo created")

    data = {
        'message': 'Initial commit', 
        'content': b64encode(file_content.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'), 
    }
    response = requests.put(f"https://api.github.com/repos/{USERNAME}/{repo_name}/contents/{file_name}", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    pprint(response.json())
```